# Comparing two or more rows in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Reference |   ID  | Length
ref101    |123456 | 10
ref101    |123789 | 5
ref202    |654321 | 20
ref202    |653212 | 40
```

I'm trying to determine which row for each row in the `Reference` column has the greatest length (based on the value in the `Length` column). For example, `ref101` with `ID` `123456` is greater in length than `ref101` with ID 123789.

I've been playing around with `.groupby()`, but am getting nowhere. Is there a way of performing this sort of operation in Pandas?

Comment: Can you show the code you've played around with `groupby()`? What's your desired output? Do you want the whole row? Just the length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's the whole row you want, then use `groupby` + `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Reference').Length.idxmax()]

  Reference      ID  Length
0    ref101  123456      10
3    ref202  653212      40
```

If you want *just* the length, then `groupby` + `max` will suffice:

```
df.groupby('Reference').Length.max()

Reference
ref101    10
ref202    40
Name: Length, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one way from `idxmax`, it will return the index with the max length of each group

```
df.groupby('Reference').Length.idxmax()
Out[495]: 
Reference
ref101    0
ref202    3
Name: Length, dtype: int64
```

Or `nlargest`

```
df.groupby('Reference').Length.nlargest(1)
Out[496]: 
Reference   
ref101     0    10
ref202     3    40
Name: Length, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

And another one:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Reference', 'Length'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Reference'])
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sort_values` on `Length`, followed by `groupby` and taking first one by `head(1)`:

```
result_df = df.sort_values('Length',ascending=False).groupby('Reference').head(1))
print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
  Reference      ID  Length
3    ref202  653212      40
0    ref101  123456      10
```